# How the startup code access the filesystem to load the kernel under /boot directory to RAM when the filesystem is mounted by the kernel?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, startup, u-boot

The kernel is usually located under `/boot` directory. When the startup program runs (like `u-boot`), it loads the kernel into RAM.

This means, `u-boot` already has access to the filesystem.

**I'm confused because the filesystem is mounted by the kernel. what I'm missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootloaders contain their own file system drivers, that’s how they can load the kernel and associated files (the initramfs) before the kernel loads. These drivers are typically simpler than the kernel’s; notably they only need to be able to read files, they don’t need to handle writes.

Even system firmware often includes file system drivers; for example UEFI can access ESP file systems (based on FAT).